# Implement scroll bar for content in samsung smart tv apps

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

I have a simple Smart TV app (`javascript` app) that shows a list of items. And I want pagination for list of items. My solution is create scroll bar for apps. But how to implement scroll bar in samsung smart tv apps. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Samsung Browser does not support displaying scrollbars, you need to implement it yourself. Also 2010-2011 TV Browser don't support horizontal scrolling.